# Не загружается модуль influxdb

Tags: яндекс-танк

При попытке использовать модуль influxdb , возникла ошибка :

```
17:47:23 WARNING: /etc/yandex-tank is not acessible to get configs list
17:47:23 INFO: No config passed via cmdline, using ./load.ini
17:47:23 INFO: Loading configs...
17:47:23 INFO: Loading plugins...
17:47:23 INFO: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 222, in configure
    self.core.load_plugins()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 275, in load_plugins
    plugin = il.import_module(plugin_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/InfluxUplink/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from plugin import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/InfluxUplink/plugin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
ImportError: No module named influxdb

17:47:23 ERROR: No module named influxdb
17:47:23 ERROR: Exception: No module named influxdb
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где должен находиться influxdb , чтобы модуль нашелся или в чем может быть проблема?

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Tank 1.7.29
- Influxdb 0.13.0

Comment: кажется, у вас не стоит https://pypi.python.org/pypi/influxdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не хватает модуля для `python`, плагин танка использует его.
Должен находиться в доступности `PYTHONPATH`. Подробнее ищите в [официальной документации по python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

---

Как правило, если вы устанавливаете модули через pip, вот это должно полечить проблему:

```
sudo pip install influxdb
```